# How to make custom validator in Polymer for paper-input with type="number"?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

The following code works well if I don't have type="number".
With type="number" I can put "..." or "--123--" or "eee" without firing validation function..
How to fix that? [see Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9HXXM6)

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'custom-validator',

        behaviors: [
            Polymer.IronValidatorBehavior
        ]
 });

</script>

<dom-module id='validation-element'>
  <template>
    <custom-validator id="valid" validator-name="validator"></custom-validator>
    <paper-input type="number" auto-validate label='Amount' validator='validator' error-message="Invalid input!">
      <div prefix>$</div>
    </paper-input>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'validation-element',

    validate: function(val) {
      var value = parseFloat(val);
      var isValid = !isNaN(value) && typeof value === "number";
      console.log('validator', isValid);

      return isValid;
    },

    ready: function() {
      this.$.valid.validate = this.validate.bind(this);
    }

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you modify the value using the arrows on the right, it does call the `validate` function. But when you modify the field directly, it is not called like you said, I suspect a bug in `<iron-input>` here:

```
_onKeypress: function(event) {
  if (!this.preventInvalidInput && this.type !== 'number') {
    return;
  }
  var regexp = this._patternRegExp;
  if (!regexp) {
    return;
  }

  // Handle special keys and backspace
  if (event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey || event.altKey)
    return;

  // Check the pattern either here or in `_onInput`, but not in both.
  this._patternAlreadyChecked = true;

  var thisChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
  if (this._isPrintable(event) && !regexp.test(thisChar)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
},
```

can you instrument the code to see if the event is stopped ?

Comment: it is more weird than that, the field has to be valid to trigger the `validate()` function of the validator... Entering "1e8" triggers it...